# Jmeter beanshell script - Polish first and last name

Tags: jmeter

i have a little problem with my jmeter test plan.
i have a jdbc request to extract customers in sql databases
from this sql query i retrieve first name and last name only
after that i have a beanshell little script to write all my customers in a csv file :

```
f = new FileOutputStream(vars.get("InputFilePath"));
p = new PrintStream(f);

nb_customer=Integer.parseInt(vars.get("NOM_#"));

for (i=1;i<=nb_customer;i++) {
                p.println(vars.get("NOM_"+i) + ";" + vars.get("PRENOM_"+i));
}

p.close();
f.close();
```

my problem is that it is an application for our subsidiary company in polska
so, all customers first and last name are in polish language with different symbol, characters.
in the csv file, they appears with a ? in spite of the real character.

can you help me please ?

thanks a lot

Ludo

Comment: Maybe the editor you are using to open the file isn't correctly configured ? Why don't you try opening it with notepad++ for example

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I open my csv file with Notepad++.

Comment: no problem, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

1. Try explicitly setting encoding to `UTF-8`, initialize PrintStream as:

   ```
   p = new PrintStream(f, true, "UTF-8");
   ```
2. Check out JMeter default encoding as:

   ```
   log.info(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
   ```

   [image: Encoding]

   If output is different from UTF-8 add the next line to *system.properties* file (lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation:

   ```
   file.encoding=UTF-8
   ```

   and restart JMeter. Alternatively you can pass it via -D command line argument like:

   ```
   jmeter -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
   ```

   See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on Jmeter properties and ways of setting and overriding them.
3. Check file contents in JMeter itself by using [FileUtils.readFileToString()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String)) method like:

   [image: From File]

Comment: Hi Dimitri,  thanks a lot for your answer and sorry for the delay but i was out of work.  i tried your configuration.    the 1 and 2 are ok for me and in my csv file, polish characters appears well but when i use the ${NOM} jmeter variable to fill the name field the polish characters appears with square character.  i tried the 3 to see if the characters displayed well but at this point the ? characters displayed.  In my example the polishChars is :   MOSTYŁZDZISŁAW and in the log there is MOSTY?ZDZIS?AW.  thanks a lot for your help.  Ludo

Comment: Even with `UTF-8` hint applied? That's weird.

Comment: yes  however in my csv file name and first name are correct  but after in the test in the name field square appears  i modified the system property file and change in my script (BSF Sampler) this line : p = new PrintStream(f, true, "UTF-8");  thanks a lot

Comment: Hi Dimitri, have you got some good news for me about this problem ? Thanks a lot, Ludo.